# Python base64 module: why use decodebytes() instead of b64decode()?

Tags: python, base64

I don't understand the purpose of `base64.decodebytes()`, its sibling function `base64.b64decode()` seems as capable of decoding base64-encoded byte strings, even if they're interspersed with newlines every 76 bytes (as produced by `base64.encodebytes()`).

Are there situations where it's preferable to use `decodebytes()` over `b64decode()`?

Comment: I think decodebytes might be faster as it takes no options.

Comment: Given that one is listed under "modern interface" and "legacy interface", it's likely a historical thing.